# Log4j Programmatically create new file for parallel runs

Tags: java, log4j

I am at somewhat of a loss. I am trying to create a new log file each time a process runs. The process can run in parallel. When it does, I would like to create a separate log for each process and have the log write to their respective log files. I am struggling with this because whatever is the "last" appender to get created, that is where the files are writing. I don't know how to fix this problem. Enough talk, here is the log4j.properties file.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CONSOLE

log4j.appender.myappender.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %x %c - %m%n

# LOGFILE is set to be a File appender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Append=false
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %x %c - %m%n
```

and the code I am using

```
    Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();
    Enumeration appenders = rootLogger.getAllAppenders();
    FileAppender fa = null;
    while(appenders.hasMoreElements())
    {
        Appender currAppender = (Appender) appenders.nextElement();
        if(currAppender instanceof FileAppender)
        {
            fa = (FileAppender) currAppender;
        }
    }
    if(fa != null)
    {
        fa.setFile(logFileName);
        fa.activateOptions();
    }
    else
    {
        log.info("No File Appender found");
    }
```

*Update

So what I am doing is running Quartz. Quartz has a job that can be called concurrently with different params. I would like each separate job run to have its own log file even though they are all calling the same class.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the last appender is only being written to because you only have one appender defined.

So when you change the file that the appender writes to, you're effectively changing the configuration for your only appender.

What I would do is create a new appender programmatically (instead of using log4j.xml/.properties) and set the file it writes to there.

http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/08/how-to-programmatically-configure-appenders-in-log4j/